# Matrix congruence - find transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-congruences

Let $A,B\in R^{n\times n}$ be symmetric matrices.

Given a matrix congruence relation:

$$
B = P^TAP
$$

Is there an analytical solution or numerical algorithm for finding the transition matrix P?

Comment: Find the eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$.  Write them as $D_1 = P_1^T A P_1$.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: This https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78106/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation might be of interest